# SQL Select statement, change Format mmddyy to dd-mon-yyyy with convert

Tags: sql, db2

I want to select field opendate `mmddyy` data type `decimal(6,0)` to `dd-mon-yyyy`. How do I modify this statement?

```
select convert(varchar(10),M.opendate, 106)  
FROM All.Customer M
```

The above results in the following error:

> [SQL0204] CONVERT in *LIBL type *N not found

Comment: That CONVERT statement looks like SQLS

Comment: i got this error : [SQL0204] CONVERT in *LIBL type *N not found.

Comment: i'm using this. DB2

Comment: I assume the numbers below 30 are in the 2000s and the numbers above 30 are in the 1900s

Comment: @EdmundXavier What's about 1-digit day, month and year dates? How do you store dates like `2001-02-03`? As `30201` or `3201` or `321`? Somehow else? Provide the corresponding date format for every possible number of digits. For example, `dmmyy` is for 5 digits, `dmyy` is for 4 digits, `dmy` is for 3 digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @InputDate VARCHAR(8)                                                      
SET @InputDate = '073019'                                                      
DECLARE @InputYear VARCHAR(4)                                                  
DECLARE @InputMonth VARCHAR(2)                                                 
DECLARE @InputDay VARCHAR(2)                                                       
SET @InputYear = '20' + SUBSTRING(@InputDate, 5, 2)                                
SET @InputMonth = LEFT(@InputDate, 2)                                              
SET @InputDay = SUBSTRING(@InputDate, 3, 2)                                    
DECLARE @OutputDate DATE                                                           
SET @OutputDate = @InputYear +'-'+ @InputMonth +'-'+ @InputDay                  
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), @OutputDate, 106)
```

Still you should know how to define the first 2 digits of the year. I have used '20' as default.